# Splash is not rendering content in page of JS Website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen, scrapy-splash

I am trying to render page using splash from this website [Chamber of Commerce](https://www.chamberofcommerce.com/search?what=Software+Company&where=Tucson%5C+Arizona) which works on js and using following code

```py
function main(splash, args)
  url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(70))
 
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

But even after wait of 70 preloader is not removing. I also remove preloader using js but content is also not loading

```py
function main(splash, args)
  url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(5))
 
  splash:runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('loaderholder')[0].style.display = 'none';")
 
  assert(splash:wait(70))
 
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

I get this screen shot

[image: Open Image]

Please help me to load the page of this website using Splash V3.5